# EPL Esper select from java Set

Tags: java, esper

I am writing select query for EPL Esper, and I need to add where clause based on info from object which stores in java set.

```
myCalss2{
    int prop1;
    String prop2;
}
    
class myClass{
    int someFiled;
    boolean foo;
    Set<myClass2> bar;
}
```

I need to compare value of prop2, but I get instance of myClass, how to get value of prop2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So "myClass" really has multiple "prop2" values.

Esper provides enumeration methods (aka. lambda funcs) so something like this would work:
 "bar.anyOf(v => v.prop2 = 'some value')"

See http://esper.codehaus.org/esper-4.10.0/doc/reference/en-US/html_single/index.html#enumerationreference

Sample in a EPL: "select * from MyClass(bar.anyOf(v => v.prop2 = 'some value'))"